# QUERY(IMPORTHTML в Google таблицах не парсит текст и числа с точкой

Tags: запрос, таблицы

Получаю таблицу с помощью:

```
 =IMPORTHTML("url";"table",1)
```

данные парсятся полностью
пример:

```
труба 20*20 | 60р         | 6м | заказать
труба 40*20 | отсутствует | 6м | заказать
труба 40*40 | 120.55      | 6м | заказать
труба 80*80 | 444р        | 6м | заказать
```

но мне нужны определенные столбцы (наименование, цена)
поэтому я использовал

```
=QUERY(IMPORTHTML("url";"table",1);"SELECT Col1, Col2")
```

в этом случае парсится так:

```
труба 20*20 | 60р
труба 40*20 | 
труба 40*40 | 
труба 80*80 | 444р
```

Что нужно сделать чтобы при использовании QUERY числа с точкой и текст тоже парсились?

Answer (score 0):

Решил проблему форматированием в текст:

```
=QUERY(ArrayFormula(TO_TEXT(IMPORTHTML("url";"table")));"SELECT Col1, Col3")
```